# How does Linux use Tree command group sorting

Tags: linux, tree

`Tree` can output the directory structure, but I want to be able to sort first by folder and then by file, consistent with the Windows display

The sample is as follows:
The first four are `directories` and the last four are `files`.

```
├── abc
├── test1
├── test2
├── www
├── zz
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.config
└── util.yml
```

Comment: For general computer hardware or software question (e.g. how to use a programm) please refer to https://superuser.com as SO is only for programming questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `tree --help`:

```
  --dirsfirst   List directories before files (-U disables).
```